# Fake Assemblies show warnings when generating shims for Interface and stubs for sealed types

Tags: c#, unit-testing, structuremap, microsoft-fakes, irepository

I have a build configured with CI post which some tests are run. Although the tests run successfully, the build shows warnings:

: Cannot generate stub for StructuremapMvc: type is sealed.
 : Cannot generate shim for IUnitOfWork: type is an interface.
 : Cannot generate shim for Repository.IRepository`1: type is an interface.

and so on.

I am using a generic repository pattern along with Unit Of Work. I have added Fake Assemblies for my MVC WebApi project (which leverages Dependency Injection using StructureMap) and Data project which contains my Repositories and UnitOfWork. I have explored this error and seem somewhat convinced that this maybe due to limitations of the Fake Assemblies, but I need to be absolutely sure that I am not doing anything wrong

Comment: if you are using ReShaper, I have seen this before with ReShaper test runner. Try Under Tools->Unit Testing -> MSTest 
then uncheck the 'Use Legacy Runner' checkbox.

Comment: Here is a UserVoice addressing this Issue: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/19224289-make-fakes-warning-some-fakes-could-not-be-genera

Answer (score 18):

The way I got rid of these warnings was to only create the shims which are needed. I added the following to the fakes config file.

```
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    <Add FullName="ATypeToShim!"/>
    <Add FullName="AnotherTypeToShim!"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
```

The ! at the end of the filter makes it a precise case-sensitive match.

For stubs, I only ever stub interfaces so its easy:

```
<StubGeneration>
  <Clear />
  <Add Interfaces ="true"/>
</StubGeneration>
```

There are more details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx#bkmk_type_filtering

Comment: also, I'd recommend to add `Diagnostic="true"` to the Fakes tag in the XML file, and read the content of the **`File-To-Fake.dll.messages`** file

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a limitation of Fakes, but neither is it really an error. What you need to know is what stubs and shims are.

Stubs are simple: they're a class which implements or extends some class, overriding every method with a delegate property and a flag determining whether it should call the base class afterward (note: that flag is for the entire stub, not per method). You use them for injecting dependencies, since they allow you to locate all your logic in lambdas *in code*, rather than in a generated class somewhere. Because they extend non-interfaces, sealed classes cannot be stubbed.

Shims are more complicated, because they apply to any instance of a specified type. Not sure exactly how this is done, but what matters to you is that since an interface cannot have an instance, it cannot have a shim. That's fine, since that's where you should be using a stub. They are dangerous, because with a shim, you override the result of a function within the entire shimscontext, and are almost exclusively when something breaks that you don't have access to - something that would be better injected.

So I wouldn't worry about the warnings. They aren't really about anything important, just making sure you know what's happening.